# using external yyin in another namespace

Tags: c++, linker, bison, extern, flex-lexer

I'm trying to use flex and bison tools in my small project.
In order to properly understand and use the tools i'm writing mini-calculator.

The problem is that i'm unable to use the variable `yyin` inside the functions of class i've declared in another namespace.

The `main()` function should read run arguments and use `Example::parse_file()` in namespace `ExNameSpace`.

While linking the compiled files i get:

```
make all
bison --defines=parser.hpp --output=parser.cpp parser.y
flex --outfile=scanner.cpp scanner.l
g++ -o program scanner.cpp parser.cpp Example.cpp -lfl 
/tmp/ccyQN7z9.o: In function `ExNameSpace::Example::parse_file(std::string const&)':
parser.cpp:(.text+0xabc): undefined reference to `ExNameSpace::yyin'
parser.cpp:(.text+0xac3): undefined reference to `ExNameSpace::yyin'
parser.cpp:(.text+0xb3e): undefined reference to `ExNameSpace::yyin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [app] Error 1
```

My suggestion is that the variable `yyin` is defined externally by flex but isn't properly ported to `ExNameSpace` namespace.

Attaching the source files that I use

**Example.h:**

```c
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#ifndef EXAMPLE_H_
#define EXAMPLE_H_

namespace ExNameSpace {
    /* global namespace variable */
    extern std::ostream *err;
    class Example {
    public:
        bool parse_file (const std::string &file);
};
}
#endif /* EXAMPLE_H_ */
```

**Example.cpp:**

```c
#include "Example.h"
namespace ExNameSpace {
    std::ostream *err = &std::cout;
    Example::Example() {}
    Example::~Example() {}
}
```

**parser.y:**

```c
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Example.h"

void yyerror (const char *);
int yylex();

using namespace ExNameSpace;
%}

%%
/* bison rules */
%%

void yyerror(const char *message)
{
  extern int yylineno;
  *err << "(line " << yylineno << ") " << message << std::endl;
}

bool Example::parse_file(const std::string &file)
{
  extern FILE* yyin;
  if(!(yyin=fopen(file.c_str(), "r")))
  {
    *err << "Could not open " << file << std::endl;
    return true;
  }
  int result=yyparse();
  fclose(yyin);
  return result;        
}
```

**scanner.l:**

```c
%{
#include "parser.hpp"
#include "Example.h"

using namespace ExNameSpace;
%}

%%
/* flex rules */
%%
```

**Makefile:**

```c
all: app
app: scanner.l parser.y
    bison --defines=parser.hpp --output=parser.cpp parser.y
    flex --outfile=scanner.cpp scanner.l
    g++ -o program scanner.cpp parser.cpp Example.cpp -lfl 

clean:
    rm parser.hpp parser.cpp scanner.cpp
```

Comment: Maybe try `extern "C" FILE * yyin;`...

Comment: Now i get this:
`parser.y: In member function ‘bool       ExNameSpace::Example::parse_file(const string&)’:
parser.y:62:10: error: expected unqualified-id before string constant
parser.y:63:8: error: ‘yyin’ was not declared in this scope
parser.y:72:10: error: ‘yyin’ was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Please review the "informational popups" on your tags before you tag your question.  I removed the Flex tag as this has nothing to do with the Adobe/Apache UI framework and added the gnu-flex tag which is for the lexical parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is declaration

```
extern FILE* yyin;
```

in the function `Example::ParseFile`.  Since this declarator has no explicit scope, and the containing method is part of namespace `ExNameSpace`, the declaration is implicitly in that namespace.  But as you never define `ExNameSpace::yyin` anywhere, you get link failures.  The default `yyin` created by bison is in the global namespace.  So you need to change this line to

```
extern FILE * ::yyin;
```

or just get rid of it altogether, as the file-scope declaration of `yyin` should already be visible at this point in the file, so there's no need for a local declaration to shadow the file-scope one.